# Why isn't feedforward+feedback higher performance than just feedback?

Tags: feedback, feedforward

This questions related to feedforward (FF) and feedback (FB) interactions.
As an example, say there's a control system keeping a car centered in a lane while driving. Say the car includes a FF sensor (like detecting sideways wind, or an inclinometer for sideways road slope), and a FB sensor (like finding the lane markings) that feeds a control law that interacts with a steering motor.

**1)** Running FF by itself works fine (say using inverse plant models.)
Running a FB loop by itself works fine. (Say LQGI, so the response dynamics are **predetermined** via models. Maybe this is relevant.)
When combining them, I would have thought the performance due to combined efforts would be BETTER than either one by itself.

In simulations, what I'm seeing is the exact same performance when FF is run along with FB, as when only FB is run by itself:

- **When FF is activated**, the FB loop command signal is reduced by the same amount that the FF has contributed. That is, FB sees a smaller error, and so the final performance ends up the same.
- **When FF is deactivated**, FB quickly fills the gap left by FF, so performance again is the same.
  This could, again, be the byproduct of a model-based controller where i define the FB system's expected response dynamics, but I define that only for the FB system, not FF+FB, so it may make sense for the FB system to "throttle back" when FF is helping out.

**2)** Seemingly, there should be a specific relation needed between the dynamics of FF and the FB loop, to make the performance from their combined efforts greater than just FB.  That is, FF is most effective when FB is physically not capable of responding fast enough due to it sensor or loop dynamics, etc.
Even in the case with similar dynamics between FF and FB, say a case with suboptimal FB loop tuning, I would have thought that adding FF would strictly improve performance.

**Question**: In the case that the FF and FB have similar dynamics, how can I set up FB in a way that it **DOES NOT** take into account the FF's positive impact, so that the combined behavior is higher performance? That is, so that FB acts with the same commands to the plant, as if FF were inactive.

Naively, one method seems like it'd involve backing out the impact of the FF (how the plant would respond to the FF command) and adding that back to the FB loop's error. This seems highly error-prone though, and I'm sure there are many official methods for this.

Comment: In your simulations, how much noise does sending (e.g. your wind sensor) have?

Comment: In my sims, there isn't any noise added (as i'm debugging this question). Why do you ask?

Comment: Because with noise, there's a reason to design the fb for a maximum bandwidth, which without noise isn't necessary

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In the FB system, there is noise. But if FB is set for a max BW accordingly (as i've also done in sims), then even here FB throttles back when FF commands are present, since the error it seems is smaller. In other words: i can't find a way for FF to contribute such that FB+FF is beyond FB's set performance.